# Help with equation for non-linear point movement

Tags: trigonometry

I'm actually trying to solve a problem in Unity but the question is more related to the math I think.

I want to move a point in non-linear way so that Y change is smaller at the beginning and bigger (change) at the end.
At start I have 2 points with coordinates P1(X1,Y1) and P2(X2,Y2).
To get linear movement from P1 to P2 I use normalized (-1 to 1 for X and Y) vector between two points by substracting P1 from P2.

I need help understanding how to make Y change non-linear (e.g. something like Y = X³) - the smaller difference between X2 and X1, the bigger difference between Y2 and Y1.

Sorry if the question is confusing.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you want the change in $y$ to be inversely proportional to the change in $x$. You might represent this as $\Delta y= \frac{k}{\Delta x}$

Comment: @H.sapiensrex It's amazing! It is exactly what I was looking for!
One last question - how to make the path/graph... rounder? And possibly to control this "roundness"? "k/Δx" is closer to 90 degree angle - up until small Δx, Δy is almost a straight line. https://www.transum.org/Maths/Activity/Graph/Desmos.asp

Comment: @H.sapiensrex Maybe it will be interesting for you. While looking for solution for another problem I stumbled upon following equation $$y=e^{-x}$$ So for original solution something like $$y=5*e^{-0.25 * x}$$ should work.